# Does the "print" function run in a new subprocess or something similar?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using praw to get new submissions from reddit:

```
for submission in submissions:
    print('Submission being evaluated:', submission.id)
    p = Process(target = evaluate, args = (submission.id, lock))
    p.start()
```

When using this code I sometimes get ids that link to older submissions. 
So I changed my script to check if the submissions are new:

```
for submission in submissions:
   if ((time.time()-submission.created) < 15): #if submission is new
            lock.acquire()
            print('Submission being evaluated:', submission.id)
            lock.release()
            p = Process(target = evaluate, args = (submission.id, lock))
            p.start()
        else:
            lock.acquire()
            print("Submission "+submission.id+" was older than 15 seconds")
            lock.release()
```

But for an extended period of time the else part didn't get executed even though I got a fair amount of old submission ids with the previous script.

So my question is, when I run `print(submission.id)` is it running in the background when the subprocess is created, maybe causing a problem and changing the value of submission.id or is it just some coincidence that with the second script I got no old submissions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `Process`?

Comment: Process from multiprocessing. I'll add it to the question

Comment: What do you mean by "gets messed up"?

Comment: I'm using praw, it streams submissions to me from reddit. It is supposed to give me new submissions but sometimes it just throws me an old one. Is there any chance that the "print" before the process creation changes the id or is it safe to use it?

Comment: probably 2 concurrent `print` instructions.

Comment: Your update still doesn't describe what you mean by "`submission.id` gets messed up sometimes".

Comment: I'm feeling that it's just a praw bug. With new submissions it will randomely give you some old ones too. By messed up I meant I also get ids from older submission (I'm really confused sorry about that). But the fact that with the second code there are no old submissions completely confused me and I wanted to know if maybe the print command could cause an error that changes the value. It was a quite stupid assumption to be honest I think I'll just delete this and stop confusing people with nonesense. Sorry and thank you for trying to help me

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, no.

`sys.stdout`, the stream `print` writes to, is usually line buffered though (though that shouldn't matter in this case, as `print` writes a newline character (unless told not to)), and is shared between threads and subprocesses (unless explicitly unshared).

Without knowing more about the code around this, it's hard to say more. (Who knows, maybe you have a background thread somewhere in there that sneakily changes `submission.id`?)

*EDIT*:

The new information in the original post, namely that

```
 print('Submission being evaluated:', submission.id)
```

is being printed, not

```
 print(submission.id)
```

is critical.

Each argument of a `print()` call is printed atomically, but if two processes or threads are `print()`ing simultaneously, let's say `print('a', 'b')`, it's entirely possible that you get `a a b b` instead of `a b a b`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for answering. I'll upate the answer to give more info

Comment: Oh that's good to know. I think that it's just some praw bug that you randomely get older submission with the new ones. The confusion started because with the second script there were no older submissions for an extended period of time and I wanted to know if it is possible that printing and immediatly sending a variable to a process could change it's value by accident. Quite a stupid assumption tbh... Thanks for the usefull inforrmation though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I like to use for safely printing to the console. That is the proper use of Lock(), use it around very simple operations. I actually use it in a class, so I dont pass around the lock object as in the below example, but same principle.

Also, the answer is *likely* yes, but it's more uncertain than certain. Are you also using a lock everytime you read and write `submission.id`? Generally, if you have an object shared by multiple processes, its best to do this, and, also best to use the `Value` class from the `multiprocessing` library, since value objects are designed to be safely shared between processes. Below is a trivial but clear example without processes (thats your job!).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, #... 

myLock = Lock()

myID = ""

def SetID(id, lock):
    with lock:
        id = "set with lock"
    return

def SafePrint(msg, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print(msg)
    lock.release()
    return

SetID(myID, myLock)
SafePrint(myID, myLock)
```

Comment: `Lock`s can be used as context mangers, so code like this can be simplified by writing `with lock:`  and then indenting the statement(s) following it that required exclusive access to the associated resource(s)—i.e. it's not necessary to explicitly `acquire()` it before each critical section and remember to `release()` it afterwards.

Comment: Exactly correct, good point, changed one of the functions to demonstrate both.